# Show action caused Mongoid Criteria error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid

I am simply trying to access the show page through my index page of an event but I keep getting this mongoid error-

```
Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound at /events/%23%3CMongoid::Criteria:0x007f8ac1da9578%3E
```

`Summary:
  When calling Event.find with an id or array of ids, each parameter must match a document in the database or this error will be raised. The search was for the id(s): # ... (1 total) and the following ids were not found: #. Resolution:
  Search for an id that is in the database or set the Mongoid.raise_not_found_error configuration option to false, which will cause a nil to be returned instead of raising this error when searching for a single id, or only the matched documents when searching for multiples.`

### Controller

```
  def index
    @event = Event.all
  end

  def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end
```

### Routes

```
  resources :events do
    resources :leads, only: [:new, :create]
    resources :registrations, only: [:new, :create]
  end
```

### Index View

```
<ul>
  <% @event.each do |e|  %>
  <li><%= link_to e.title, event_path(@event) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= link_to e.title, event_path(e) %>
```

You have to call the `link_to` method for each `events` which is accessible with the `e` variable from you `@event.each do |e|` call.

Also, I suggest renaming `@event` by `@events` since it holds more than one `Event`. So in your controller:

```
def index
  @events = Event.all
end
```

and in your view:

```
<ul>
  <% @events.each do |e|  %>
    <li><%= link_to e.title, event_path(e) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: I am using mongoid (3.0.23), both the above give me undefined method for id. Any ideas?

Comment: 1 final question... I have a slug field, then in the model define the to_params method as slug and then in the show controller I have @event = Event.find_by_slug(params[:id]).

Comment: What's your question ? I suggest asking it in a new thread anyway ;)

Comment: Thanks Pierre, I started a new thread and got my answer @event = Event.find_by(slug: params[id]) :)